# TypeScript: How to extract value from object property without specifying all the properties of the object

Tags: typescript

In my use case i receive a JSON object as a response from a server. This object contains over 200 properties, out of which I only care about 2 of them. So if I have the response object looking like this:

```
{
a: "a",
b: "b",
.
.
.
z: "z"
}
```

But I only want let's say a and z, how do I do this is typescript without having to define the entire response object?
This does not work and gives `property does not exist on object`

```
const myObject: MyObject = {
     myA: resObject.a,
     myZ: resObject.z
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are not showing the definition of `MyObject`. Is that something you wrote that has the `a` and `b` properties? You also do not show how `resObject` is declared. If you don't or cannot provide a full interface, declaring it as `any` makes things easier.

Comment: Thank you, declaring it as any solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "any", to make full use of Typescript, consider something like this, using type narrowing:

```
const resObject = {
    a: "sdfsdf",
    b: 'sad',
    c: "Sdf",
    z: "sdfzzzzz"
}

interface MyObject extends Record<string, any> {
    myA: string, 
    myZ: string
}

const isMyObject = (candidate: any): candidate is MyObject => {
    return ('a' in candidate && 'z' in candidate)
}

if (!isMyObject(resObject)) throw new Error('Not MyObject');

const myObject: MyObject = {
    myA: resObject.a,
    myZ: resObject.z
}
```